# Jquery Accordion and Fading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to create a jquery accordion that fades the header of the accordion out when the page is loaded then fades it in when the mouse hovers. The accordion also opens when the mouse hovers. I am able to get all of this working, the problem I am having is when the accordion opens the header moves away and the mouse is no longer on it to keep it lit. I would like the links to keep the header lit as well as if the mouse is on the header itself. Below is the code that I wrote for it.

```
<html>
<head
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://accidentalwords.squarespace.com/storage/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://accidentalwords.squarespace.com/storage/jquery/jquery-custom-181/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">

<style = "css/text">

.links {
        font-family: "Georgia", "Verdana", serif;
 line-height: 30px;
        margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 5px;
       }

.Title {
        font-family: "Geneva", "Verdana", serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: left;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 border-bottom: solid 2px #25FF00;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".Title").fadeTo(1,0.25);
$(".Title").hover(function () {
   $(this).stop().fadeTo(250,1)
   .closest(".Title").find(".links").fadeTo(250,0.75);
}, 
function() {
$(this).stop().fadeTo(250,0.25);
});
});

$(function() {
 $("#accordion").accordion({
  event: "mouseover"
});
});

</script>
<p>&nbsp</p>
<div id="accordion">

<div class="Title"><a href="#"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #25FF00;">Reference</a></div>
<div class="links">
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #25FF00;">Jquery Documentation/Help</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #25FF00;">Stack Overflow</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #25FF00;">w3schools.com</a><br>
</div>

<div class="Title"><a href="#"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #FF7200;">Gaming</a></div>
<div class="links">
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #FF7200;">Jquery Documentation/Help</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #FF7200;">Stack Overflow</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #FF7200;">w3schools.com</a><br></div>

<div class="Title"><a href="#"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Grub</a></div>
<div class="links">
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Jquery Documentation/Help</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Stack Overflow</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">w3schools.com</a><br>
</div>

<div class="Title"><a href="#"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #F8FF00;">Drinks</a></div>
<div class="links">
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #F9FF00;">Jquery Documentation/Help</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #F8FF00;">Stack Overflow</a><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #F8FF00;">w3schools.com</a><br>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U83Rd/) for you... here is the script I used:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
    // Fade out all Titles except for the active one
    $(".Title:not(.ui-state-active)").fadeTo(1,0.25);
    $(".Title").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(250,1)
            .closest(".Title").find(".links").fadeTo(250,0.75);
    }, function() {
        // Fade out all titles except the active one
        $(".Title:not(.ui-state-active)").fadeTo(1,0.25);
        // Make sure the active title is faded in
        if ($(this).is('.ui-state-active')) {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(250,1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it is exactly what I needed it to do. The next problem that I am having is that the first panel, labled "Reference", is shown open when the page loads. Is there a way that I can have that hidden when the page loads and show after the user mouses over "Reference". But still keep the same smooth up/down motion?

Comment: I updated my answer above and the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/U83Rd/1/), just add `collapsible: true, active: false` to the options when you initialize the accordion.

Comment: Thanks, I really like the jsfiddle "online render" that you used to do this. How did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Each item in your accordion consists of a div.Title and a div.links. Wrap each of those accordion items in another div and apply your hover function to that:

```
<div class="accordionItemWrap">
    <div class="Title"><a href="#" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Grub</a></div>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Jquery Documentation/Help</a><br>
        <a href="#" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">Stack Overflow</a><br>
        <a href="#" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE; color: #00DEFF;">w3schools.com</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Title").fadeTo(1,0.25);
    $(".accordionItemWrap").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.Title').fadeIn();
            $(this).find(".links").fadeIn();
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).find('.Title').fadeOut();
            $(this).find(".links").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work because of the way that jquery reads the code. It loses the header part and calls the "content" as the header. Think of it as pushing everything down. Also I am just looking for it to fade to an opacity not totally fade out.